# JSON for Objective-C messes up my array

Tags: objective-c, json, xcode4

This is a strange error and I'm not sure if I'm using JSON correctly. When I get a response from the server with a proper array, JSON chews it up, turning most of the values to zero and I think it might've forgotten by keys also.

```
2011-08-01 16:08:15.981 My Alerts[2746:b303] From Server: {"cycleStart":"May 1, 2011","cycleEnds":"May 29, 2011","avg_usage":0,"estimate":0,"totalBudget":0,"Usage":0,"Cost":0}
2011-08-01 16:08:15.982 My Alerts[2746:b303] After JSON: (
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   "May 29, 2011",
   "May 1, 2011",
   0
)
```

Here is my code showing where JSON is being used.

```
NSString *post = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"username=%@&acct=%@", username, account];
NSLog(@"POST: %@", post);
NSData *postData = [NSData dataWithBytes: [post UTF8String] length: [post length]];

// Submit login data
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] autorelease];
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString: @"http://***.****.***/file1.php"]];
[request setHTTPMethod: @"POST"];
[request setValue: @"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];
[request setHTTPBody: postData];

// Retreive server response
NSURLResponse *response;
NSError *err;
NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&err];
if (returnData == nil) {
    NSLog(@"ERROR: %@", err);
}

NSString *content = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:[returnData bytes]];
NSLog(@"From Server: %@", content); // <---JSON string returned perfectly from server

if (content != @"FAIL")
{
    NSArray *viewDetail = [[NSArray alloc] init];
    viewDetail = [[[content JSONValue] allValues] mutableCopy]; // <--JSON appears to be chewing it up
    NSLog(@"After JSON: %@", viewDetail); // <--Array is now messed up here.

    // Do stuff with viewDetail array

    [viewDetail release];
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't see what's wrong. You wanted `allValues`, you got all the values. Aside from the ordering, the "from server" and "after JSON" are equivalent.

The ordering is not there because `NSDictionary` (which your `JSONValue` returns, I believe) does not guarantee order. And the keys are not there because you did not request keys, you requested the values.

If you wanted keys, there's `allKeys` method. And if you wanted a specific value, there's `objectForKey:` or `valueForKey:`. You can also use various enumerators. For instance, I believe this should work:

```
NSDictionary *dict = [content JSONValue];
for (id key in dict) {
    NSLog(@"key: %@   value:%@", key, [dict objectForKey:key]);
}
```

Comment: Ok, I see what I'm looking at it wrong. But is there a way to get the array to maintain its keys so I can reference it by key when I need the value?

Comment: You don't have an array. You have `NSDictionary`. Array's keys are always integers from 0 to size - 1. EDIT: actually, you have an array once you butcher your `NSDictionary` with `allValues`. That's like saying "I know I bought this liver, but I want a bunny, can you turn it back into one?"

Comment: Very witty. ^^; That got me moving again. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

JSON isn't chewing anything up - most of your values are, in fact, 0. You're not working with plain arrays, you're working with key-value pairs. In Objective-C these become an `NSDictionary`.